# SQL Server Management Studio disable add table dialogue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When creating a view in SQL Server Management Studio, when you go to create a view it by default opens up the add table dialogue. Our database has thousands of tables and this now takes 2+ minutes to show up.

Is it possible to disable this help?

Comment: Try `Tools-->Options-->Designers-->Table and Database Designers-->Launch add table dialog on new diagram`

Comment: I would recommend not using the visual designer for view. Just write the t-sql.